# VMWare workstation on Windows 2008 R2 server won't install

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2008-r2

I am attempting to install VMWare Workstation on Windows 2008R2 server.  When I attempt the install, the installer crashes with a dialog box as below with the diagnostics shown below.  This happens with installers for VMWare Workstation 7 and 8.

What is causing this and how does one fix the problem so VMWare will install?

[image: VMWare installer crashing dialog]

The contents of the diagnostic are as follows:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: VMware-workstation-full-8.0.3-703057.exe
  Application Version:  8.0.3.29699
  Application Timestamp:    4f9f5d7a
  Fault Module Name:    windowscodecs.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17514
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ce7ba3a
  Exception Offset: 00001f9d
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   00000008
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: b80f
  Additional Information 2: b80fa8aa693f9630e858f5a976d06b8a
  Additional Information 3: 2ade
  Additional Information 4: 2adea04e810ac36f6067d59a816f636a

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable the built in virtualization feature Hyper-V in windows server 08. Only one virtualization system can be installed in a system

Answer (score 1):

First, just to rule it out, redownload the application and/or do a CRC check and just make sure it is fine.

Next, I have never tried, so, I can't say for certain - but, based on the text (and look) of the dialog box and personal experience of how VMWare Workstation works, I would say that you need to install the Windows Desktop Experience Feature - this will install codecs and other items.

Again, not seen this before, however, Workstation does funky things with pretty much everything, and if the installer is failing on windowscodecs.dll, that is my only thought.

This being said, it should fail on the application - not the installer, so, again, it is a guess!

Comment: Desktop experience is installed.  The problem occurs on WS7 which I have from a CD in a boxed set, and the WS8 download from VMWare's site.

Comment: Also Hyper-V is not active.